# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() for length of page numbers

Tags: python, parsing

```
#The following code parses the page number from the page and therefore you can print exact number on the pages.

all_page_numbers = []
    
    # grab all the page numbers, first one is usually blank
for thematic_break in all_thematic_breaks:
        #print(thematic_break)
        page_number = thematic_break.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.get_text(strip=True)
        all_page_numbers.append(page_number)
        #print(a)
        
        #print(all_page_numbers)

        # determine the number of pages, will be used for the upcoming if conditions.
        length_of_page_numbers = len(str(all_page_numbers))
        print(length_of_page_numbers)
```

Comment: I don't think you can get that error message from this code unless you've redefined str() to return an int result.

Comment: `length_of_page_numbers = len(str(all_page_numbers))` should be `length_of_page_numbers = len(all_page_numbers)`

Comment: I tried to fix your code example indentation... did I get it right? Please post the enire error message so we don't have to guess where the problem is.